# Unable to install MongoDB PHP driver on Cent Os - Plesk Onyx?

Tags: mongodb, centos7, php-mongodb

We have multiple versions for php in centos server,currently installed mongodb3.4
but we are unable to install mongodb driver.while installing mongodb error we are facing the following issue.

[mongodb driver error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgke7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

By default there is no mongo module loaded for Plesk PHP5.6 version:

```
# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -m | grep mongo
#
```

You can compile by yourself it with

```
# yum install plesk-php56-devel gcc make
# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/pecl install mongo
# echo "extension=mongo.so" > /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/mongo.ini
# plesk bin php_handler --reread
```

After that you can see that mongo.so module is loaded:

```
# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -m | grep mongo
mongo
```